# Manga where the main character is in a cultivation world but he isn’t suited for cultivation

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

The main character is a genius at a young age, creating machines. But when it's time to check if he can cultivate it says he cannot. Later on he finds out he is a descendant or part of an ancient god clan and he is planning on rebuilding it. He has a dice that can control life, death, luck, curses and more depending on what it rolls.

Comment: He has a turtle birthmark in his ass cheek

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TZuHHntID4 doesn't look 100%